# Change connection definitions for clear_border in Python

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-image

I've been using [clear_border](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.clear_border) from scikit-image and [label](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) from scipy to identify areas of adjacent pixels in a 2d array of 1s and 0s. I use `clear_border` first, which removes all groups of 1 that are touching the edge, and then label the groups that are left with `label`.

My question is, with `label` a custom `structure` parameter can be passed. This determines what is defined to be connected, and in my case it basically allows me to decide whether diagonals are connected. To be concrete, in the array

```
[[0,0,0,0,0]
 [0,1,0,0,0]
 [0,0,1,1,0]
 [0,0,0,0,0]
 [0,0,0,0,0]
```

`label` would find 2 independent objects if `[[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]]` is used for `structure`, but only one if `[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]` is used. The problem is, `clear_border` has no such option and works the same as `label` when `[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]` is used (in other words, `clear_border` always defines diagonal pixels to be connected).

So my problem is just that I need to use a function exactly like `clear_border`, but one that does not define diagonal pixels to be connected. The analogue of passing `structure=[[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]]` to `label`.

### Update

Based on Juan's answer, here is my general function that I was looking for.

```
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label

def clear_border_adjacent(matrix):
    """
        clear_border from skimage.segmentation considers diagonal pixels to be connected, 
        so e.g. all structures will be removed in all of these:
                [[0,0,0,0],                [[0,0,0,0],                [[0,0,0,0], 
                 [0,1,1,0],                 [0,1,1,0],                 [0,1,0,0], 
                 [0,0,0,1],                 [0,0,1,1],                 [1,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0]]                 [0,0,0,0]]                 [0,0,0,0]]
        This function clears the border but only considers adjacent pixels connected, 
        so ex 1 and 3 would still have one structure in output but ex 2 would have 0.
    """
    border_cleared = clear_border(label(matrix)[0])
    border_cleared[border_cleared > 0] = 1
    return border_cleared
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you can use label first, then clear border, to achieve the same result? If there is a reason why this fails, please make a feature request on https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues

Comment: You're right, thanks!